# Reference request: gluing/pasting perfect graphs on a clique?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

What's the correct reference please for the proof that pasting/gluing two perfect graphs on a clique results in another perfect graph?

Comment: This observation is simple enough to prove that I would not be surprised or offended if a paper using the result called it "an easy exercise".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct ref is
@article {Gal62,
    AUTHOR = {Gallai, T.},
     TITLE = {Graphen mit triangulierbaren ungeraden {V}ielecken},
   JOURNAL = {Magyar Tud. Akad. Mat. Kutat\'o Int. K\"ozl.},
    VOLUME = {7},
      YEAR = {1962},
     PAGES = {3--36},
   MRCLASS = {55.10},
  MRNUMBER = {0145508 (26 #3039)},
MRREVIEWER = {J. W. Moon},
}